# Retrieve array stored in the dataframe column for each row using scala apark

Tags: arrays, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

Following dataframe belongs to me

```
+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
|value                          |feeling                  |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
|Sam got these marks            |[sad, sad, dissappointed ]|
|I got good marks               |[happy, excited, happy]   |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

I want to iterate through this dataframe and get the array of marks column per each row and use the marks array for some calculation method.

```
def calculationMethod(arrayValue : Array[String]) {
//get averege of words
}
```

output dataframe

```
  +-------------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------
    |value                          |feeling                   |average       |
    +-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
    |Sam got these marks            |[sad, sad, dissappointed ]|sad           |
    |I got good marks               |[happy, excited, happy]   |happy         |
    +-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

I am not sure how I can iterate through each row and get the array in the second column that can be passed into my written method. Also please note that the dataframe shown in the question is a stream dataframe.

**EDIT 1**

```
val calculateUDF = udf(calculationMethod _)
    val editedDataFrame = filteredDataFrame.withColumn("average", calculateUDF(col("feeling"))) 

def calculationMethod(emojiArray: Seq[String]) : DataFrame {
val existingSparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
    import existingSparkSession.implicits._
    val df = emojiArray.toDF("feeling")
    val result = df.selectExpr(
      "feeling",
      "'U+' || trim('0' , string(hex(encode(feeling, 'utf-32')))) as unicode"
    )
    result
}
```

I'm getting the following error

> Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
> is not supported

Please note that initial dataframe mentioned in the question is a stream dataframe

**EDIT 2**

This should be the final dataframe that I am expecting

```
    +-------------------+--------------+-------------------------+
    |value              |feeling       |unicode                  |
    +-------------------+--------------+-------------------------+
    |Sam got these marks|[]     |[U+1F600 U+1F606 U+1F601]|
    |I got good marks   |[]        | [U+1F604 U+1F643 ]      |
    +-------------------+---------------+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `transform` the arrays instead of using a UDF:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "unicode", 
    expr("transform(feeling, x -> 'U+' || ltrim('0' , string(hex(encode(x, 'utf-32')))))")
)

df2.show(false)
+-------------------+------------+---------------------------+
|value              |feeling     |unicode                    |
+-------------------+------------+---------------------------+
|Sam got these marks|[, , ]|[U+1F600, U+1F606, U+1F601]|
|I got good marks   |[, ]    |[U+1F604, U+1F643]         |
+-------------------+------------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: im getting the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] is not supported"

Comment: @tharindu it's not possible to call methods on a spark dataframe inside a UDF. You can consider using `transform` on the array. If you could provide an example dataframe I can give it a try.

Comment: I have provided the expected dataframe under the edit 2

Comment: I am not getting any output. No error is thrown but there is nothing printed in the console.

Comment: Sorry there was some network issue thats why. Its working properly. thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: one thing to know an array with 2 or more emojis shows unicodes in a different manner. eg - []  [U+1F6220001F614]

Comment: @tharindu You need to ensure that each array element is 1 single emoji

Comment: oh ok. my emoji array isn't comma separated